React Native quick crypto Encryption build failed
In basic RN app after adding react native quick crypto the android and ios build are failing with error


Task :react-native-quick-crypto:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED
C/C++: /Users/projects/encryption/encryptSample/node_modules/react-native-quick-crypto/android/CMakeLists.txt debug|arm64-v8a : com.google.prefab.api.NoMatchingLibraryException: No compatible library found for //ReactAndroid/fabricjni. Rejected the following libraries:


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-quick-crypto:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.


[CXX1214] /Users/projects/encryption/encryptSample/node_modules/react-native-quick-crypto/android/CMakeLists.txt debug|arm64-v8a : User has minSdkVersion 21 but library was built for 23 [//ReactAndroid/fabricjni]

If i change the minsdk version to 23 the build failed with
error: Error: Unable to resolve module missing-asset-registry-path from /Users/projects/encryption/encryptSample/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/UI/LogBoxImages/chevron-right.png: missing-asset-registry-path could not be found within the project or in these directories:
node_modules/react-native/node_modules
node_modules

1 | �PNG
2 |
3 |
4 | IHD�8��BIDATx�c�dx � �P�?�ǣ���%���*         ��1A� �ȑ!��h   ${�2���钓4E��IEND�B�
at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/projects/encryption/encryptSample/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:138:15)
at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/projects/encryption/encryptSample/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:231:43)
at /Users/projects/encryption/encryptSample/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:156:21
at resolveDependencies (/Users/projects/encryption/encryptSample/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/buildSubgraph.js:42:25)
at visit (/Users/projects/encryption/encryptSample/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/buildSubgraph.js:83:30)
at async Promise.all (index 12)
at async visit (/Users/projects/encryption/encryptSample/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/buildSubgraph.js:92:5)
at async Promise.all (index 10)
at async visit (/Users/projects/encryption/encryptSample/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/buildSubgraph.js:92:5)
at async Promise.all (index 9)

